# What's the "DS" and its detailed explanation in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shell

In our site shell directory file, I found one line of code like below:

```
fopen(Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'sitemap'.DS.'sitemap_new.xml','w+');
```

I guess the '**DS**" is meaning a 'slash', but I can't search its **specific source** and **detailed explanation**. Could anybody give some information?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's Magento's constant which is a simple abbreviation for PHP predefined constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ([PHP: Predefined Constants Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php))

If you look at app/Mage.php you can see the assignment in one of the first lines after block comment:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Why use constant over a simple `/` or `\` ?

The directory separator character depends on operating system.

You want your code to be compatible with as many systems as possible because you don't know what the server OS will be where your code will be executed (usually).

Comment: When you give PHP a path, using `/` works on Mac, Linux _and_ Windows. Aka `fopen(Mage::getBaseDir().'/sitemap/sitemap_new.xml','w+')` works everywhere. When PHP is giving _you_ a path, yes, use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. A small nit.